# How to work with arrays without knowing offset

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I am paring some .ini files via PHP

ini file looks like:

```
07=TEXT1
93=TEXT2
00=TEXT3
01=TEXT4
83=TEXT5
```

Some simple script to print value if you know offset will loooks like

```
public function pasrseString($path)
{
    $ini = parse_ini_file($path);
    print_r($ini["01"]);
}
```

Problem is that I don't know what file I give to script in future so I dont know what offset will be there. 
So I need somehow print both value and offset. In other words:
I need some foreach which print result to table like:

```
    id  |   value
--------|----------
    01  |  TEXT4
--------|----------
    93  |  TEXT2
--------|----------
    07  |  TEXT1
--------|----------
    83  |  TEXT5
```

Can someone advise me with this?

Comment: Check `foreach($array as $key => $value)`

Comment: using @b0s3's method, your id will be `$key`, and value will be `$value`. Then, have fun displaying it as you wish :)

Comment: Thanks @b0s3, this helped me

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
foreach($ini as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}
?>
```

This will output something like:

```
93 = TEXT2

07 = TEXT1

83 = TEXT5
```

Comment: you have a syntax error at foreach expression. not "at" would be "as" :)

Comment: Whoopsie! Thanks dude!